# How to calculate the average power for a square wave DC signal

Tags: ac, analog, signal

1. Now, suppose that a square wave generator is used as the source. If the square wave
   signal has a peak-to-peak of 20 V and a zero average value, determine the average
   power supplied by the source connected to 1 k ohms resistor.
2. Next, if the square wave signal has a peak-to-peak of 20 V and a 10 V average value,
   determine the average power supplied by the source.

My attempt for Q 1. Half of peak to peak voltage which is 10. Then, average power is 0.1 W.

I am not sure what to do for question 2.

Comment: Hint: draw the square wave. A 20V peak to peak with zero average is actually swinging between +10V and -10V.

Comment: Thanks. so for question 1 the average power is zero?

Comment: @Crazy no... let me splain

Comment: About question 2, putting average voltage into the average power equation?

Comment: @Trevor Can you help me with question 2 as well.

Comment: Your answer to 1 is correct, but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Power into the load is positive, power back to the source is negative. So, I think for one complete cycle, the total energy is zero by conservation of energy.

Comment: The resistor is still dissipating energy, no matter the direction of current flow.

Comment: Oh! I mistakenly treat it same as a capacitor and inductor.

Comment: Can someone explain to me for the case of square wave. I am confused. I understand for sine wave that we must take the V r.m.s in order to get the average power of the load(resistor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

In the first case your square waive is 20V biased around ground, so it is actually +-10V

The power for the upper half is \$\frac{V^2/R}{2}\$ =\$\frac{10^2/1000}{2} = 0.05W\$

By the same equation the power for the lower half is \$\frac{-10^2/1000}{2} = 0.05W\$

So the total power is \$0.1W\$

In the second case when biased to \$10V\$

The upper half becomes \$\frac{20^2/1000}{2} = 0.2W\$

The lower half becomes zero in this case.

The actual formula for any bias is...

\$P\$ = \$\huge\frac{(V_{pk-pk}/2)^2 + V_{bias}^2}{R}\$

Comment: More complete than mine; I like the pictures.

Answer (score 2):

In case 1:

The signal is going from +10V to -10V; ignoring transition time, there is *always* 10V across the resistor, yielding \$ \frac {V^2} {R}\$ = 100mW

For case 2:

The signal is switching from 0V to 20V with (assuming a proper square wave) a 50% duty cycle.

The formula for such a situation is \$ \frac {V^2} {R} \cdot DC\$ which yields 200mW.

Note that this is only for a square wave under the circumstances shown.